# How to convert the array of results returned as an array of jQuery objects?

Tags: jquery

When I have `$("someSelector")` it returns an array of `Node` elements. How can I convert each `Node` as a jQuery object so that I can perform jQuery functions on them?

In short and as an example, how do I achieve the equivalent of getting the `.text()` function results on every element, besides the first, of a jQuery object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please know that when you use something like:

```
// Selecting all <h1> tags. 
var headings = $( "h1" );
```

here `headings` is now a jQuery element containing all the `<h1>` tags already on the page. This can be verified by inspecting the `.length` property of `headings`:

```
// Viewing the number of <h1> tags on the page.
var headings = $( "h1" ); 
alert( headings.length );
```

Thus, when you use `$("someSelector")` this, you will not need to convert it again to a jQuery object, as it is already a jQuery object and you can perform all jQuery functions on them. But as this `$("someSelector")` is a collection we can not use `.text()` directly on it, we will need to loop over each element in that collection.

You can use jQuery [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/) method here, which iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element like:

```
$("someSelector").each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

As mentioned in [docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

> The `.each()` method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I convert each Node as a jQuery object so that I can perform jQuery functions on them?

Use `.map` to pass every element to `$`:

```
const $elements = [...$("someSelector")]
  .map(elem => $(elem));
```

That'll give you an array of jQuery objects, each of which contains a single element. But this is a bit weird.

> how do I achieve the equivalent of getting the .text() function results on every element, besides the first, of a jQuery object?

If you need to use jQuery, if you want the text of all besides the first, slice the array to select all elements but the first, then map it:

```
const $texts = [...$("someSelector")]
  .slice(1)
  .map(elem => $(elem).text());
```

But if you're retrieving the text, I'd prefer to use `textContent`, no need to transform each element to a jQuery object first:

```
const $texts = [...$("someSelector")]
  .slice(1)
  .map(elem => elem.textContent);
```